# lmer Model failing to converge with random effects structure

Tags: r, lme4, convergence, random-effects

I am trying to use intercept and slope effects in my random effects structure (best model fit) and I get the following errors when I do.

```
MLM <- lmer((sqrt(degrees))~ Condition*CogLoad + (Video|Subject),
data=dataset)
```

> Warning messages:
> 1: In commonArgs(par, fn, control, environment()) :
> maxfun < 10 * length(par)^2 is not recommended.
> 2: Inoptwrap(optimizer, devfun, getStart(start, rho$lower, rho$pp),  :
> convergence code 1 from bobyqa: bobyqa -- maximum number of function
> evaluations exceeded
> 3: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par,
> ctrl = control$checkConv,  :   Model failed to converge with max|grad|
> = 0.0704516 (tol = 0.002, component 1)

When I run just intercept effects I do not get these errors though:

> Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod'] Formula: (sqrt(degrees)) ~
> Condition * CogLoad + (1 | Video) + (1 | Subject)    Data: dataset
>
> REML criterion at convergence: 183048.6
>
> Scaled residuals:
> Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max
> -3.7418 -0.6048 -0.0377  0.5293  5.9471
>
> Random effects:  Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
> Subject (Intercept) 0.01385  0.1177
> Video    (Intercept) 0.15947  0.3993
> Residual             0.67628  0.8224
> Number of obs: 74731, groups: Subject, 27; Video, 11
>
> Fixed effects:
> Estimate Std. Error t value
> (Intercept)              2.260374   0.123524  18.299
> ConditionMap             0.022744   0.050473   0.451
> CogLoadNone              0.047609   0.008152   5.840
> ConditionMap:CogLoadNone 0.051590   0.013228   3.900
>
> Correlation of Fixed Effects:
> (Intr) CndtnM CgLdNn
> ConditionMp -0.121
> CogLoadNone -0.032  0.068
> CndtnMp:CLN  0.016 -0.130 -0.507

Would really love some input if someone knows why the first model is not converging appropriately.

Comment: Googling the first warning (`maxfun < 10 * length(par)^2 is not recommended`) got me [this helpful thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2014q2/022084.html), which suggests trying `control=glmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=1e5))`

Comment: I have tried using the control command and it does not help with convergence issues. I end up getting the same errors when I use a control command.